# Scoverage + jenkins: How to fail build if coverage criteria is not met? Is it possible using Scoverage report plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, scoverage

Is it possible using SCoverage report plugin for Jenkins?

If yes could you please let me know the step.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved, but with some workaround, SCoverage plugin can be used to generate coverage report and two reports gets generated  one is scoverage.xml and another is cobertura.xml, I have used coburtura plugin to publish this report and the apply threshold condition.